# Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^2 + (-1)^n n + 1}{5n^2 + 2} = \frac{1}{5}$ using definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm using Rudin's definition of limit where a sequence converges: $p_n$ converges if $\exists p \in X \text{ such that } \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } \forall n \geq N, d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$. Using the definition, this is what I know that I have to show that:

$| \frac{n^2 + (-1)^n n + 1}{5n^2 + 2} - \frac{1}{5} | = |\frac{n^2 + (-1)^n n + 1 - n^2 - 2/5}{5n^2 + 2}| = | \frac{n(-1)^n + 3/5}{5n^2 +2}| = | \frac{n (-1)^n + 3}{25n^2 + 10}| $

I know I'm supposed to show that 
 $| \frac{n (-1)^n + 3}{25n^2 + 10}|$ < (some n) < (some N) = (some epsilon).

But I really don't know how to proceed from here. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I added some explanation that I think it would be helpful for future proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know that for any $\epsilon>0$ exists some $N$ such that

$$\left| \frac{n (-1)^n + 3}{25n^2 + 10}\right|<\epsilon,\;\forall n\ge N$$

Now observe that $|(-1)^n|=1$, and using triangle inequality we have that

$$\left| \frac{n (-1)^n + 3}{25n^2 + 10}\right|\le\frac{|n|+3}{|25n^2+10|}<\frac{n+3}{(n+3)n}=\frac1n$$

So choosing $N>\frac1{\epsilon}$ is enough.

---

**General strategy to prove that $a<b$**

If we want to prove that $a<b$ many times the more useful strategy is to find some expression $c$ such that $a\le c$ and where we can prove easily that $c<b$.

Then $a\le c<b$ implies that $a<b$. In the above case I search for some expression bigger than $\left| \frac{n (-1)^n + 3}{25n^2 + 10}\right|$ that it would be easier to prove. Then I though that $1/n$ probably would be bigger so I focused to see if $\left| \frac{n (-1)^n + 3}{25n^2 + 10}\right|\le\frac1n$, what fortunately was true.

Then it is easier to solve the inequality $\frac1n<\epsilon,\;\forall n\ge N$ instead of the original.

For the case where absolute values are involved it is very useful to consider the use of the triangle inequality (sometimes the use of the reversed triangle inequality).

The axioms of an ordered field as $\Bbb R$ are very useful to deduce if some quantity is less, bigger or equal to something. By example: in the above proof I used the fact that

$$\epsilon>0\implies\epsilon\neq 0\implies\frac1{\epsilon}\cdot\epsilon=1\implies N\cdot\epsilon>1\text{ whenever }N>\frac1{\epsilon}$$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a little confused on the line where  $\frac{ |n| + 3}{|25n^2+10|} < \frac{n+3}{(n+3)n}$. And wouldn't $| \frac{n(-1)^n +3}{25n^2+10} | = \frac{|n|+3}{|25n^2+10|}$ since we have $|(-1)^n| = 1$?

Comment: By the triangle inequality we have that $$|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$$ I applied this in the numerator, then we have that $|n(-1)^n+3|\le |n(-1)^n|+|3|=n+3$ because $n\ge 0$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! And since we have $(n+3)n < 25n^2 + 10$, we have that the whole fraction is larger. Thanks!

Comment: You can see that $n^2+3n<25n^2+10$ implies that $24n^2-3n+10>0$ what is true for all $n\in\Bbb N$. The line $\frac{ |n| + 3}{|25n^2+10|} < \frac{n+3}{(n+3)n}$ means that solving for $1/n$ it solves for $\left| \frac{n (-1)^n + 3}{25n^2 + 10}\right|$ too.